# unable to get css or xpath response

Tags: css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get meta tags attribute value from html content, but unable to get the value.

The website is: https://www.sunnxt.com/movie/inside/

this gives html page with lot of information and i want to extract

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="2xB02QJaF8oUkLmj3QVtcKaOD1F9sOkyH8qZ9j3W">
```

the value of content attribute.
I have tried with

css Selector:

```
'meta[name="csrf-token"]::attr(content)'
```

and 
xpath selector:

```
 '//meta[@name="csrf-token"]/@content'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getAttribute`

```js
var meta = document.querySelector("meta");
var content = meta.getAttribute("content");
console.log(content);
```

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="2xB02QJaF8oUkLmj3QVtcKaOD1F9sOkyH8qZ9j3W">
```

Comment: this will work here if you write separate html but it is not working on that site